# Spring: "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined" when testing

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, h2

I have been trying to test the DAO layer of an application, however I keep getting this error.

Here is the Test class

RegionDAOTest.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.teamw.ibt.dao.impl.RegionDAOImpl;
import com.teamw.ibt.model.Region;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(locations = "classpath:app-context.xml")
public class RegionDAOTest extends AbstractDAOTest {

 @Autowired
 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
 @Autowired
 private RegionDAOImpl regionDAOImpl;

 @Before
 public void setUp(){
 }

 @After
 public void tearDown(){
 }

 @Test
    public void testContext() {
        assertNotNull(regionDAOImpl);
    }

 @Test
 public void FindByCodeTest() {
    Region region = regionDAOImpl.findByCode("1");
    assertEquals('1', region.getCode());
    assertEquals("Region 1", region.getName());
 }
}
```

RegionDAOImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class RegionDAOImpl implements RegionDAO {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public RegionDAOImpl() {
}

public RegionDAOImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}


public void insert(Region region) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO IBT.REGION (code, name) VALUES ('" + region.getCode() + "','" + region.getName() + "');";
    jdbcTemplate.update(query);
}

public Region findByCode(String code) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM IBT.REGION WHERE CODE = '" + code + "';";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new ResultSetExtractor<Region>() {
        @Override
        public Region extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return new Region(
                    rs.getString("code"),
                    rs.getString("name")
                );
            }

            return null;
        }
    });
}
}
```

app-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

<!-- Initialization for data source -->
 <bean id="dataSource" 
   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem"/>
   <property name="username" value="SA"/>
   <property name="password" value="test"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="JdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
 </bean>

<bean id="regionDAOImpl" name="regionDAOImpl" class="com.teamw.ibt.dao.impl.RegionDAOImpl">
  <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

As far as I know, I have set up everything correctly, but for some reason it says dataSource is not defined.

EDIT: Here is the log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:201) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener$DbUnitTestContextAdapter.getApplicationContext(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:256) ~[spring-test-dbunit-1.2.1.jar:na]
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.getDatabaseConnectionUsingCommonBeanNames(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:135) ~[spring-test-dbunit-1.2.1.jar:na]
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:112) ~[spring-test-dbunit-1.2.1.jar:na]
at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:87) ~[spring-test-dbunit-1.2.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'regionDAOImpl' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.3.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) ~[spring-test-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [app-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
... 65 common frames omitted
```

Comment: 1) Why don't you @autowire RegionDAOImpl into the test? You don't really want to use new()

Comment: 2) You should really use placeholders in your sql string rather than string concatenation. could be a potential security/sql injection...

Comment: 3) You don't need to @ autowire the jdbctemplate into the dao in 3 places. Just @ autowire it in once i.e. field OR setter OR constructor

Comment: can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: I posted it @JérémieB

Comment: this stacktrace is not coherent with your configuration. it's looking for a bean  "dataSource" when injecting the constructor of `JdbcTemplate`. Your configuration is injecting a property, not a constructor. Either you are using a file which is not the file you posted here, or you have two "app-context.xml" in your classpath

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple wiring of JdbcTemplate in RegionDao, which you will need to change.

In the app-context, you are only referencing dataSource as a constructor-arg.
If that is what you wish to do, then app-context stays as-is, and you will need to get rid of the below method -

```
public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
```

OR , you could get rid of the constructor with JdbcTemplate and then wire the dataSource as a 'property' in the app-context.

```
<bean id="regionDAOImpl" name="regionDAOImpl" class="com.teamw.ibt.dao.impl.RegionDAOImpl">
    <!-- constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" -->
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>
```